# Use a recursive Google Sheets function to change inline labels into columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet where the creator has put labels with measures underneath them, something like this:

| Projects | Dollars | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Project: Foo** |  |  |
| Meetings | 25.00 | .5 |
| Diagnostic | 350.00 | 10 |
| Implementation | 1000 | 50 |
| **Project: Bar** |  |  |
| Meetings | 50.00 | 1 |
| Diagnostic | 100.00 | 5 |
| Implementation | 100 | 5 |
| **Project: Baz** |  |  |
| Meetings | 50.00 | 1 |
| Diagnostic | 100.00 | 5 |
| Implementation | 100 | 5 |
| etc... |  |  |

What I want to do is turn it into something I can pivot, taking all the rows with a name containing `Project` and using those as a new column, so it would output:

| Project | Task | Dollars | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Project: Foo** | Meetings | 25.00 | .5 |
| **Project: Foo** | Diagnostic | 350.00 | 10 |
| **Project: Foo** | Implementation | 1000 | 50 |
| **Project: Bar** | Meetings | 50.00 | 1 |
| **Project: Bar** | Diagnostic | 100.00 | 5 |
| **Project: Bar** | Implementation | 100 | 5 |
| **Project: Baz** | Meetings | 50.00 | 1 |
| **Project: Baz** | Diagnostic | 100.00 | 5 |
| **Project: Baz** | Implementation | 100 | 5 |

I've been playing around with `lambda` and `byrow`, but I can't figure out how to loop that project name through so it stays the same until I find a new value that starts with `Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=filter({scan(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,if(left(c,8)="Project:",c,a))),A2:C},B2:B<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

For the example table given:

```
=arrayformula({{"Project","Task","Dollars","Hours"};{tocol(regexreplace(filter(A2:A13,regexmatch(A2:A13,"Project: ")),"(Project: )(.*)","$2")&wraprows(,3,)),filter(A2:C13,not(regexmatch(A2:A13,"Project: ")))}})
```

Change the references to suit your real table. I'm assuming that (based on your example) there are a consistent number of tasks per project.